# How to process short keypress in the same time long keypress is performed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I try to write simple game in Python and PyQt4. It's simple platform game and I want to process "jump" keypress during "move" keypress.

It's like I'm holding `right arrow` key and in the same time I'm pressing `z` (or simply any key, may be shift, ctrl, cmd, alt) and I want to continue move to the right and in the same time perform jump.

When I use `keyPressEvent` it works fine with long "move" keypress but every "jump" keypress breaks the move and I need to press arrow to continue.

To better understand what I want to accomplish lets look at this:
(> is right arrow for move, z is for jump)

`key: >>>>>>>>>>>>>
.               z
.
.               o
player: oooooooo`

As you can see I'm holding `>` and player moves. In the same time when I press `z` player jumps and stops even when `>` key is still pressed.

Is it possible to do this in pyqt? Maybe I need some external library for this? Any help will be appreciated!

---

**Solved!**

Thanks to the answer from @Brendan Abel I've done everything I've needed :)
Code looks similar to this (I've simplified for clarity):

```py
class Test(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  pressed_keys = {
    QtCore.Qt.Key_Left: False,
    QtCore.Qt.Key_Right: False,
    QtCore.Qt.Key_Z: False,
  }

  def __init__(self):
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.key_action)
    self.timer.start(100)

    # definitions hidden for simplicity
    self.key_actions = {
      QtCore.Qt.Key_Left: self.player_move_backward,
      QtCore.Qt.Key_Right: self.player_move_forward,
      QtCore.Qt.Key_Z: self.player_jump,
    }

  def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    key = e.key()
    self.pressed_keys[key] = True

  def keyReleaseEvent(self, e):
    key = e.key()
    self.pressed_keys[key] = False

  def key_action(self):
    for key, is_pressed in self.pressed_keys.items():
      if is_pressed:
        action = self.key_actions[key]

        action()
        self.update()
```

My game acts now like this:
[image: jump and move]

Comment: without your keypress function at the very least, you wont get much help

Comment: maybe take a look at http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qkeysequence.html, e.g. QKeySequence(Qt.Right+Qt.Up) to handle your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to do some type of regular polling of the keyboard state to determine what controls to process.  Unfortunately, Qt doesn't have a direct API for polling keyboard state.  You'll have to keep track of which keys are down by maintaining a global map of keys that have had a *keypress* event but no *keyrelease* event.  Then poll that map at a regular interval to get the list of keys that are pressed.

```
pressed_keys = set()

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    pressed_keys.add(event.key())

def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
    pressed_keys.remove(event.key())
```

When adding keys, you can choose whether you want to add *modifier keys* (ie. shift, ctrl, alt) as well (using `event.modifiers()`), and whether the should apply to only the key they were first pressed with, or whether they should apply to all pressed keys.

You can use a `QTimer` to do the polling.  Basically, instead of `keyPressEvent` triggering your game to update, you're going to update based off of `QTimer.timeout` instead.

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(self.update_game)
timer.start(100)  # Update rate

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def update_game(self):
    if Qt.Key_Space in pressed_keys:
        ...
    if Qt.Key_Up in pressed_keys:
        ...
```

You could also choose not to use the `QTimer` to do the updates and keep using the `keypress` and `keyrelease` events to trigger the updates, but you'll still need to keep a persistent state of pressed keys.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I've seen some answers to similar questions but your answer that includes `Timer` guides me to the right tracks! It's working like a charm, all pressed keys are now fully processed and I have application independent from system "key press frequency".